# What is the simplest way to install Ubuntu on a second hard drive while already running Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

I need to do the install at home.  The hard drive will go into a computer at work for booting.  Most search results I pull up on google deal with dual booting Ubuntu from Mac/Windows.

Comment: Not clear what the question is.  Just make the second hard drive the target drive and run the installation program.  There probably isn't a lot of difference between different permutations unless you're talking about doing a mirror image on the second drive.  "Simplest" probably comes down to which method is most familiar to you.

Answer (score 1):

A few options.

1. Hook up the hard drive (maybe a second hard drive, through USB or eSATA) then insert the Ubuntu DVD and make sure you select that you want to install on the work hard drive
2. On a live Ubuntu system clone your hard drive using clonezilla or dd
3. Create a VM which uses the real hard disk as the virtual hard disk then install within the virtual environment using the Ubuntu DVD